# How to write to a read-only file in Python

Tags: python, overwrite

Is there a way to write to a read-only file in Python? I am trying to write a script which helps me add debug statements at the start of every function in a given file. But the issue I have is that before I run the script, I have to manually remove the read-only flag on the file. is there anyway I can write to read-only files without manually having to remove them? Any suggestions will be deeply appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you doesn't have permissions to write into the file, nope.

Comment: What system are we talking about? Windows / Mac / Linux? How exactly are you removing the read-only flag?

Comment: @ Viraptor : I am testing my script on both windows and mac. But the script will eventually be deployed in windows. When I open the read only file in notepad++, I have an option to remove the readonly flag.

Answer (score 7):

If the user that runs the script doesn't have permissions to write in a file, you can't edit it. Basically, you need to have the `w` permission to edit a file. See Linux file permissions for more information.
If you want to get rid of it, you should make the file writable directly, or try to change its `chmod` with the [`os` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chmod), if you have enough permission to do this:

```
>>> os.chmod('path_to/file', 0755)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try [`os.chmod()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chmod) before opening the file.